# Support for `auto&&` for MSVC++2017

Tags: c++, c++14, visual-studio-2017, c++17, auto

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44521132/1915854) they suggest to use the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename F>
class Finally {
    F f;
public:
    template <typename Func>
    Finally(Func&& func) : f(std::forward<Func>(func)) {}
    ~Finally() { f(); }

    Finally(const Finally&) = delete;
    Finally(Finally&&) = delete;
    Finally& operator =(const Finally&) = delete;
    Finally& operator =(Finally&&) = delete;
};

template <typename F>
Finally<F> make_finally(F&& f)
{
    return Finally<F>{ std::forward<F>(f) }; // This doesn't compile
    //This compiles: return { std::forward<F>(f) };
}


int main()
{
    auto&& doFinally = make_finally([&] { std::cout<<", world!\n"; });
    std::cout << "Hello";
}
```

The author linked to a demo that compiles with Clang++/G++ . However, this code does not compile for me in MSVC++2017 .

The error message is:

```
source_file.cpp(20): error C2280: 'Finally<main::<lambda_9000fb389e10855198e7a01ce16ffa3d>>::Finally(Finally<main::<lambda_9000fb389e10855198e7a01ce16ffa3d>> &&)': attempting to reference a deleted function
source_file.cpp(12): note: see declaration of 'Finally<main::<lambda_9000fb389e10855198e7a01ce16ffa3d>>::Finally'
source_file.cpp(26): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'Finally<main::<lambda_9000fb389e10855198e7a01ce16ffa3d>> make_finally<main::<lambda_9000fb389e10855198e7a01ce16ffa3d>>(F &&)' being compiled
        with
        [
            F=main::<lambda_9000fb389e10855198e7a01ce16ffa3d>
        ]
```

So what is the difference between `return { std::forward<F>(f) };` and `return Finally<F>{ std::forward<F>(f) };` that one compiles, but the other doesn't?

[Demo](http://rextester.com/QFU34551)

Comment: `auto&&` should be supported by MSVC.

Comment: `Finally<F> make_finally(F&& f)` should that not be `Finally<std::decay_t<F>> make_finally(F&& f)`?

Comment: Why is this compiling with Clang?  The return from `make_finally` wants to call the (deleted) move constructor for `Finally`.  Event if it is optimized out, it should still need to be available.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm If `make_finally` is a candidate for RVO, since C++17 guarantees RVO, you don't need the move constructor IIRC

Comment: Am I missing something or this should work with `auto const & doFinally = ...` as well?

Comment: People! There is NO moving here. `make_finally()` creates a `Finally<F>` directly in the return object, which is then bound to the reference `doFinally`. No moving happens anywhere, even without the new value categories, even with `-fno-elide-constructors`.

Comment: The code you've posted [compiles fine on MSVC 2017](https://godbolt.org/g/pnva2c)...

Comment: @Barry That's only true in C++17. Why does this work in C++11 as well?

Comment: @cdhowie : That's true of all instances of list-initialization, from C++11 onwards.

Comment: @cdhowie That was true in C++11.

Comment: Derp, I forgot that we're binding the return value to a reference. Ignore me.

Comment: I've found that whether it compiles or not depends on whether `return { std::forward<F>(f) };` or `return Finally<F>{ std::forward<F>(f) };` is used. I've updated the question.

Comment: @SergeRogatch : As was said, list-initialization constructs directly into the return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So what is the difference between `return { std::forward<F>(f) };` and `return Finally<F>{ std::forward<F>(f) };`

The former initializes the return object in place. So when you have:

```
X foo() { return {a, b, c}; }
auto&& res = foo();
```

This will construct an `X` in place and then bind `res` to it. There is no moving anywhere at all. Not a move that would be elided thanks to RVO, not a move that would be elided thanks to guaranteed elision in C++17 with the new value categories. At no point are we even considering moving anything. There is only ever one `X` (even in C++11, even with `-fno-elide-constructors`, because there is no constructor call to elide).

By contrast, this:

```
X bar() { return X{a, b, c}; }
auto&& res2 = bar();
```

Before C++17, would create a temporary `X` and then move it into the return of `bar()`. This would be a candidate for RVO and the move would surely be elided away, but in order to elide a move, a move has to actually be possible to begin with. And in our case, `X`'s move constructor is deleted so this code is ill-formed. This leads to a situation that is best described by Richard Smith's comment in [P0135R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html):

> ```
> // error, can't perform the move you didn't want,
> // even though compiler would not actually call it
> ```

*After* C++17, there is no temporary. We have a prvalue of type `X` that we are using to initialize the return object of `bar()`, so we end up simply initializing the return object from the prvalue's initializer. The behavior is equivalent to the `foo()` example above. No move will be done.

Comment: I wouldn't have said "directly initializes", too easy to confuse.

Comment: @T.C. Removed the word direct everywhere. Hard to carefully pick words that don't mean different things in different contexts.

Comment: "There is no moving anywhere at all. Not a move that would be elided thanks to RVO, not a move that would be elided thanks to guaranteed elision in C++17 with the new value categories. ". This is extreme confusing, because you make a difference between "no moving at all" and "moving that is guaranteed to be elided in C++17". Therefore, minus 1

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Can't please everyone I guess. I'm trying to establish that the reason for the lack of move *isn't* due to C++17. It doesn't help that the actual paper is called "guaranteed copy elision"